# Pass dynamic value to react native Modal View from flatList Item

Tags: reactjs, react-native, modal-dialog, react-native-flatlist, react-native-modal

I have a FlatList like...
`<FlatList data={data} keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}renderItem={({item,index}) =>(<NewView id={item.id} index={index}/>) }/>`Now  for render Item
`const NewView = ({id, index}) =>{return(<TouchablOpacity onPress={()=> openModal()}> <Text>{id}</Text></TouchableOpacity><Modal animationType='fade' transparent={true}visible={userOptionShowModal}onRequestClose={() =>setUserOptionShowModal(false)}}><Text>{?? ==>id}</Text></Modal>); }`Now when i want to show modal on Pressing each flatlist item, its working but when Pressing one flatlist item showing the modal but in the modal item i cannot show the index or id or any dynamic value passed (how?) of that particular flatListItem ... Please help how to achieve it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this behavior in many ways. One of the easiest way is to create a state that holds this information, then on modal close, you reset its value.

First, add this useState:

```
const [passedData, setPassedData] = useState({});
```

Then when you call the onPress, add all the info you need:

```
<TouchablOpacity onPress={()=> openModal({id, index})}>...</TouchablOpacity>
```

PS: openModal({id, index}) is same as openModal({id: id, index: index})

Then in your openModal function, add this:

```
const openModal = ({id, index}) => {
...
setPassedData({id, index})
}
```

Then you can access it in your modal (Don't forget to reset the passed data onCloseRequest or anytime you close the modal):

```
<Modal
  animationType="fade"
  transparent={true}
  visible={userOptionShowModal}
  onRequestClose={() =>{
  setUserOptionShowModal(false)
  setPassedData({})
 }}>
  <Text>id : {passedData.id}, index: {passedData.index}</Text>
</Modal>
```

Comment: without using state variable can we do that?

Comment: @React_Coder you need a State to make it re-render. React Redux does the job too (You will still need to create a state inside the redux store).
https://react-redux.js.org/

Comment: can we make it using context api?

Comment: Yes you can, after all it works almost the same way